# Adding multiple records into django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views, multiple-entries

I would like to be able add multiple records at a time in django admin.

models.py

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    sort = models.IntegerField()
    photo_category = models.ForeignKey(Photocategory)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title_url = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    main_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='images/photo/')
    # size is "width x height"
    cropping = ImageRatioField('main_image', '350x350')

    def image_thumbnail(self):
       return '<a href="/media/%s" target="_blank"><img width="160px" src="/media/%s"/></a>' % (self.main_image, self.main_image)

    image_thumbnail.allow_tags = True
    image_thumbnail.short_description = 'main_image'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
class PhotoAdmin(ImageCroppingMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):

    prepopulated_fields = {'title_url': ('title',)}
    list_display = ('title', 'photo_category', 'image_thumbnail', 'sort')
    list_filter = ['photo_category']
    admin.site.register(Photo, PhotoAdmin)
```

Screenshot:
[image: django admin panel]

Is there a way I could do lets say 5 at a time on the 1 screen, it is very slow filling that out 1 by 1. I can do it in mysql with SQL query but I would like to achieve this here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey Yes **this is possible but Out of the Box**,,

Here is what you will have to do:

1. Define a **Formset** (to create multiple photo forms) in `form` Attribute of PhotoAdmin
2. You will see a **formset on the add photo Admin page**, and should work correctly. If you don't then you can over-ride the templates by providing `add_form_template` and `change_form_template` **attributes in Admin** and display that form-set templates.
3. Handle **Saving of Multiple objects in the Formset**

For example:

```py
# admin.py

@admin.register(Photo)
class PhotoAdmin(ImageCroppingMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'title_url': ('title',)}
    list_display = ('title', 'photo_category', 'image_thumbnail', 'sort')
    list_filter = ['photo_category']
        
    form = MyFormset
    add_form_template = "photo/admin/my_add_form.html"
    change_form_template = "photo/admin/my_change_form.html"
```

This is a rough workflow, you will have to try this and make modification if required.
You can refer to this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options

Comment: Is there a way you would post a little example how to do that? I am not that advanced in django, it can be small working example. Thanks

Comment: It would be better for your learning if you could read about using Formsets in Django.. I can provide links for reading: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/  It would help you learn more quickly

Comment: This answer is actually not correct. If you want to add, edit multiple objects at once, have a look at django-bulk-admin https://github.com/purelabs/django-bulk-admin

Comment: @chhantyal bulk-admin is out of date for newer django